# iOS push notifications not working in flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app needs push notifications. I just follow the [flutterfire guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview), with android working correctly but not for iOS app... I consider the error are in configuration of notifications, because the code never execute `print("PUSH RECEIVED");` inside `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen()` or `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage()`.

My flutter doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.27.0-4.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.985], locale es-ES)
    • Flutter version 1.27.0-4.0.pre at C:\SDKs\flutter
    • Framework revision f8cd24de95 (3 months ago), 2021-02-16 11:24:17 -0800
    • Engine revision 1d537824d6
    • Dart version 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-30.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • SM G986B (mobile) • ... • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
    • Edge (web)        • edge        • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.62

• No issues found!
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
#https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android
firebase_core: ^1.2.0
firebase_analytics: ^8.1.0
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.0
#https://dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications/install
flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0+4
```

Main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  ...

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  bFirebaseMessaging.init();

  ...

  runApp(MyApp());
}

...

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  ...

  static Future<void> _throwGetMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    print("PUSH RECEIVED");
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    bFirebaseMessaging.showPushFromBackground(message);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print("PUSH RECEIVED");
      bFirebaseMessaging.showPush(message);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_throwGetMessage);

    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

PodFile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '8.0.0'

...

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.0.0'
end

...
```

bFirebaseMessaging.dart:

```
class bFirebaseMessaging {

  ...

  static Future init() async {

    // Declaration of variables
    FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    NotificationSettings settings = await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );

    print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');

    if(Platform.isIOS){
      await firebaseMessaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

In the other hand I configured whole Firebase:

- Created new iOS app
- Added Team ID and Appstore ID
- Added APNS autentication key with Key ID and Team ID

Extra files: [image: GoogleService-Info.plist], [image: Signing & Capabilities]

Any ideas the reason that iOS devices not receiving puhs notifications? I think I gives all necessary information if you need something, tell me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same issue with firebase push notification in ios. My android push notification was working properly but not in ios.

What I did was to follow the instruction provided by firebase to integrate Push notification(Not the flutter guide but the ios one)
Follow this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

In ios user have to give permission to send push notification for them unlike android
so the thing you want to do is add the below code to AppDelegate.swift

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
  let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
    options: authOptions,
    completionHandler: { _, _ in }
  )
} else {
  let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Hope this works

Comment: helpful link, didn't find it in the docs

Comment: what should I do to listen to notifications in the  ``` Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) ``` in the dart code >> using apns

Comment: Those who still have the problem can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/76349360/11156666